# Proof that some vector space is a subspace and finding a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ denote the set of polynomials with degree at most $2$ with real coefficients. Let $V$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ for which $V=\{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}_2[x]:p(0)+p'(0)=0\}$. Prove that $V$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ and find a basis for $V$.

My solution: For subspacehood, note that $p(x)=0$ is in $V$. Now assume $p,q\in V$. Then $p(0)+p'(0)=0, q(0)+q'(0)=0$.

Adding these together and simplifying we have $(p+q)(0)+(p+q)'(0)=0$.

For $p\in\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ and a scalar $k\in\mathbb{R}$:

$p(0)+p'(0)=0\Rightarrow kp(0)+kp'(0)=0\Rightarrow (kp)(0)+(kp)'(0)=0$.

Hence $V$ is a subspace.

I don't know how to find a basis though... can anybody provide a solution?

Comment: Basis would be $\{x^2,x-1\}$ since the constant plus the linear coefficient has to be zero.

Comment: A general element of $V$ is $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, but $a, b$ and $c$ are not independent. How are they related?

Comment: Is it really part of the question to prove $V$ as you defined is a basis for $\mathbb R_2[x]$?

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathcal V:=\{f(x)\in\Bbb R_2[x]:f(0)+f'(0)=0\}$ is a $\Bbb R_2[x]$ linear hyperplane since $\mathcal V$ is by definition the kernel $\ker(\Psi)$ of the non-trivial $\Bbb R_2[x]$ linear functional $\Psi:=\varphi\circ(I+\frac{d}{dx}))$  where $I,\varphi,\frac{d}{dx}$ are defined here, respectively, by $I:f(x)\mapsto f(x)$, $\varphi:f(x)\mapsto f(0)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}:f(x)\mapsto f'(x)$.
Therefore, because $\dim(\mathcal V)=2$, the linearly independent $\mathcal V$ subset $\{x-1,x^2\}$ must span $\mathcal V$.